# Python Seleniumurllib3.connectionpool:Retrying not working?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have been assigned a quiz to analyze data from Pocket option, so I need to pick up the data from this URL: https://pocketoption.com/en/cabinet/demo-quick-high-low/. Specifically, I need to extract the price at each second as per the figure.[image]

I used the following code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Setup Chrome options

def web_driver():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--verbose")
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920, 1200")
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    return driver

browser = web_driver()

# Go to a webpage
browser.get('https://pocketoption.com/en/cabinet/demo-quick-high-low/')
for element in browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="layer plot"]'):
  print("1")
  print(element.text)

# Wait for the dynamic element(s) to load
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

try:
    # Define the XPath for the dynamic element containing the data
    dynamic_element_xpath = "//div[@class='chart']"  # Replace with actual XPath

    # Wait for the element to be present in the DOM
    dynamic_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='chart']")))
    
    # Extract and print the data
    dynamic_data = dynamic_element.text
    print("here")
    print(f"Dynamic Data: {dynamic_data}")

except Exception as e:
    print("Error occurred:", e)

finally:
    # Close the WebDriver
    driver.quit()
```

But the output was

```
    WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7d1c6cb200d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')': /session/459c44d1e876dd6b8600e69cdef44093
WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7d1c6cb22d10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')': /session/459c44d1e876dd6b8600e69cdef44093
WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7d1c6cb22440>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')': /session/459c44d1e876dd6b8600e69cdef44093
Error occurred: Message: 
Stacktrace:
#0 0x57e77e500d33 <unknown>
#1 0x57e77e1bdf87 <unknown>
#2 0x57e77e20dc0e <unknown>
#3 0x57e77e20dd11 <unknown>
#4 0x57e77e259004 <unknown>
#5 0x57e77e23736d <unknown>
#6 0x57e77e256297 <unknown>
#7 0x57e77e2370e3 <unknown>
#8 0x57e77e1ff044 <unknown>
#9 0x57e77e20044e <unknown>
#10 0x57e77e4c5861 <unknown>
#11 0x57e77e4c9785 <unknown>
#12 0x57e77e4b3285 <unknown>
#13 0x57e77e4ca41f <unknown>
#14 0x57e77e49720f <unknown>
#15 0x57e77e4ee028 <unknown>
#16 0x57e77e4ee1f7 <unknown>
#17 0x57e77e4ffed4 <unknown>
#18 0x7bf790161ac3 <unknown>
```

Is there any suggestion to extract these values (0.64798)? I'm using Google Colab for this task. I tested the connection and everything is OK and tried to print the code and it worked.